# Как добавить в vue файлы автодополнение импортов и ех подсветку?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, импорт

Неохото постоянно писать вручную.

Охото импортировать компоненты и многое другое как в react, например функция которая не импортирована подчеркивается красным и потом нажимая на нее через ctrl + . можно было выбрать от куда испортировать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как такое сделать?**